# ASP.NET MVC 4 WEBAPI Entity Framework 4.3: What is the best way to save "many to many" from Collection

Tags: ef-code-first, many-to-many, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-4.3

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 WEBAPI project with Entity Framework 4.3
It has 3 tables in my MS SQL DB:

Meal
MealCategory
Category

The second table is the connection of 1 and 3 (many to many connection).
Here is my Meal model:

```
[Table("Meal")]
public class Meal
{
[Key]
public long MealID { get; set; }
public string MealName { get; set; }
...
public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my Category model:

```
[Table("Category")]
public class Category
{
[Key]
public long CategoryID { get; set; }
...
public virtual ICollection<Meal> Meals { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using code first. And have a DbContext:

```
public class DgDbContext : DbContext

{
    public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Meal> Meal { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Entity<Meal>().
        HasMany(c => c.Categories).
        WithMany(p => p.Meals).
        Map(
         m =>
         {
           m.MapLeftKey("MealID");
           m.MapRightKey("CategoryID");
           m.ToTable("MealCategory");
         });
    }
}
```

Also I have an action:

```
// POST /api/<controller>/<action>
public HttpResponseMessage PostMeals(IEnumerable<Meal> meals)
{
  ...
}
```

So the question is: what is the best way to save all my meals to DB with all connections to Category and MealCategory?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
using(var ctx = new DgDbContext())
{
    foreach(var meal in meals)
    {
        ctx.Meal.Add(meal);
    }
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

?